# Why does my View frame size change when using Autosizing in Portrait mode?

Tags: ios, size, frame, autosize

I'm trying to understand how Autosizing works. After reading some posts like [How to Automatically Resize a UIView When The Orientation Changes](http://userflex.wordpress.com/2011/09/22/autoresize-uiview-orientation/), [iOS 4 iPhone Rotation, View Resizing and Layout Handling](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IOS_4_iPhone_Rotation,_View_Resizing_and_Layout_Handling), [Understanding UIView autoresizing](http://www.techpaa.com/2012/05/understanding-uiview-autoresizing.html), ...

I think that Autosizing only works when there is orientation changes so that the View can be displayed properly, but it doesn't. It does resize my View frame size either when I'm only in Portrait mode. Why is that ?

[image]

Comment: did you figure this out and was it my solution below?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot fully tell from your screen shot, but I assume that in your storyboard the view is in the 4 inch dimensions. Then you are using the 3.5 inch simulator. Since you have made your sizing constraints say in essence...

"Keep my view this far from the top and this far from the bottom, and resize its height to force this"... Your view will shrink that half inch to make sure it matches your constraints.

Try running it in the 4 inch simulator and see if that works.